# Alphabetize a string

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to take a string and sort it alphabetically:

```
function AlphabetSoup(str) { 
    var newstr = str.split("");
    newstr.sort();
    newstr.join();
    newstr.replace(",","");
    return newstr; 

}
```

Comment: Great.  What's your question?

Comment: I get an error when I run the code. I think there is an issue with the join function

Comment: @mikeandike And what is the error? How do you use your function? What is the output? What is the expected output? Put in a little effort in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
newstr = newstr.join();
```

You're making a string here, but not assigning it.

Also, there is no need for your replace step if you join with an empty string.

```
'asdf'.split('').sort().join(''); // returns 'adfs'
```